# Show CiviEvent registration details via dashboard or view?

Tags: civievent

How would one approach letting a user login and see their registration details for an event? We find that many users lose their initial email and we'd like to streamline the process. Looking for any good ideas/support! The contact dashboard seems to show the event one has signed up for, but I did not see it display the actual price set/registration details of the event. Did I just miss something? I'm thinking about making a View of some sort to do this, so we can attach to their user page or something.

CiviMobile seems like a cool way to do this: https://civicrm.org/blog/skornien/event-participants-management-in-the-new-version-of-civimobile  we'll consider it for 2020, but it's too late for our current event.

Most recent Civi / Drupal

Comment: I would go down the Drupal VIews approach since it is so easy to define what you actually want them to see. You can also make a Drupal Views Block and set that to show on their civi Dashboard if you prefer to keep the info in one place

Comment: I want it to show essentially the table someone receives in their confirmation email for their event purchase. It's proving very difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make a View for Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.x that produces a block which can be placed on the user page (/users/) via Panels or Panelizer.

The limitation I see currently is that it needs to specify the price set ID of the event in a filter to show the appropriate information. We are going to use it for our yearly conference so someone can login and see what they purchased.

It will only show the items, sorted by price field weight (in order), if the participant has a status that is registered, pay later, etc. This should all be adjustable (it's Views)

Views export below:

https://pastebin.com/iLSNYP4W

Answer (score 3):

You can use for it CiviMobile if a user who registered has a CiviCRM account. 
Only CiviCRM users can login in CiviMobile. So they will see the list of events where he is registered and their tickets on these events with all information (role, price, name, status).

Comment: This is an acceptable answer but we'll probably look to implement 2020.